# no suitable method found for put(int, ArrayList)

Tags: java

I have a piece of code:

```
    public static void Sort(int N, int k, int[][] books) {
        TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int curDisorder = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                for (int u = j+1; u < k; u++) {
                    if (books[i][j] > books[i][u]) {
                        curDisorder++;
                    }
                }
            }
            map.put(curDisorder, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(books[i])));
        }
        for (ArrayList<Integer> list: map.values) {
            res.add(list);
        }
        System.out.print(res);
    }
```

However, it has error at map.put() which says:

```
method Map.put(Integer, List) is not applicable
argument mismatch: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>
reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `books[i]` is an `int[]`, so `Arrays.asList(books[i])` is a `List<int[]>` with one element, not a `List<Integer>`

Comment: Can not I use int[] as the parameter of asList()?

Comment: That is the key! Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

i think you must put the type of collection for your Arraylist:

```
map.put(curDisorder, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(books[i])));
```